# В обработчике аякса не работают сесси

Tags: php, сессия

Всем привет. Я создал сессию на странице, и тут же ее вывел. Все работает. Далее создал сессию, и послал аякс запрос на сервер. В обработчике мне должно вывести значение сессии. Мне вывело просто пустую строку. Сессии в начале файла я стартовал. В чем проблема?

Comment: по каким адресам идут запросы? Возможно кука устанавливается не для всего домена, если у вас на них весит. Так же играет значение имя сессии

Comment: я правильно понял - два раза создается сессия?.. не нужно так...

Comment: "по каким адресам идут запросы? Возможно кука устанавливается не для всего домена, если у вас на них весит. Так же играет значение имя сессии" имя сессии вот такое - id_poll. А как установить куку для всего домена
"я правильно понял - два раза создается сессия?.. не нужно так..." - нет, не правильно

Answer (score 1):

Я создаю сессии, на куках. При чем контролирую это сам:

```
if(empty($_COOKIE['auth'])){
    $key=sha1(uniqid('G-',TRUE));
    setcookie('auth',$key,2592000,'/');
    session_id($key);
}else session_id($_COOKIE['auth']);
```

Таким образом, кука вешается на основной домен и сессия действует не зависимо от адреса.

Еще один момент - использование flash upload. Флеша при запросе на сервер не отправляет куки, поэтому сессия работать не будет. И идентификатор сессии нужно передавать каким-нибудь другим образом.

Comment: Не, мне такой код не пойдет. И флеш мне ник чему. Я просто создаю сессию на странице и сразу ее вызываю, она выводится. А в обработчике аякса она не отображается - почему? сессии я стартую(session_start()) и до старта сессии вывода чего либо НЕТ